# Signtool error The specificed PFX password is not correct

Tags: certificate, sign, pfx, signtool

I have a new certificate from DigiCert .pfx file  which when I try to use it for signing gives the error "The specified PFX password is not correct"  However the password works fine when installing it locally.  I have tried without specifying a password without success.  The certificate was given to me buy another person who purchased it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue but solved it by removing " from the password.

Before: signtool.exe sign /f mycert.pfx /p "password" /v /t http://... "application.exe"

After: signtool.exe sign /f mycert.pfx /p password /v /t http://... application.exe

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well when trying to sign dll files with post-build events in Visual Studio. I found out that the issue was having special characters like percentage sign (%) and comma (,) in the password. I fixed it after setting a new password without those special characters.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is the encryption of the PFX could be unrecognized, for example a newer SHA256 encrypted cert cannot be used to sign on older SDK's

See related SO answers:
[signtool - the specified PFX password is not correct from new machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548158/signtool-the-specified-pfx-password-is-not-correct-from-new-machine?r=SearchResults&s=2|108.2803)

and

[Why I get "The specified PFX password is not correct" when trying to sign application with signtool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082333/why-i-get-the-specified-pfx-password-is-not-correct-when-trying-to-sign-applic)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Azure Devops where I was using a Command Line task:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "D:\Cert\CodeSigning.pfx" /p %_pwd123_% /d "" /du "" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256 "D:\Build\Installer.msi"
```

This resulted in 'The specified PFX password is incorrect'.
But I was able to take the actual script command from the failed pipeline, copy it into a cmd prompt on the build machine and run it (without any changes) successfully.

I also tried creating a pipeline variable as I've seen others do and use that in the command like `$(pfxPwd)`. That also seemed to translate perfectly when run but still failed.

The solution was to use the pipeline variable but include it in the command like this instead: `%pfxPwd%`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "D:\Cert\CodeSigning.pfx" /p %pfxPwd% /d "" /du "" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256 "D:\Build\Installer.msi"
```

Perhaps this trouble was caused by the password beginning and ending with `%`.
But since this certificate and password came from IT, there were no other options.

Note: I later discovered that if I change the variable type to 'secret' it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to sign from an Azure DevOps pipeline using a **PowerShell** task.

Before: (getting same error mentioned in question) **(password in double quotes)**

```
CustomToolForSigning.exe --action SigningWithPfx --pfx-file $pfxPath --working-directory $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --pfx-password "$(PrivateKey)"
```

After: (worked) **(password in single quotes)**

```
CustomToolForSigning.exe --action SigningWithPfx --pfx-file $pfxPath --working-directory $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --pfx-password '$(PrivateKey)'
```

The error appeared because my password contained '$' symbols, such as $a$b$c$d. It wasn't working with double quotes since PowerShell attempted to resolve variables. When I changed it to single quotes, it acted as a string, and everything worked perfectly.